# find list of files in a directory programmatically C++ MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm trying to find list of files in a directory programmatically and I've written the following code

```
CStringArray CCL2ProjectDirectoryPage::GetAllFilesNames()
{
  WIN32_FIND_DATA fileData;
  memset(&fileData, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));
  HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile("d:\\test\\*", &fileData);

  CStringArray strArray;

  while(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    strArray.Add(fileData.cFileName); // the problem is that the fileData.cFileName always contains "."

    if(FALSE == FindNextFile(handle, &fileData))
    break;
  }
  FindClose(handle);

  return strArray;
}
```

The problem is that the fileData.cFileName always contains ".".
"." with the first file, ".." with the second file and so on.
what is wrong with this code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. The filenames "." and ".." are normal, you just need to ignore them.

Comment: They're directory names, not filenames, and you can't count on them being present - the root directory doesn't have `..`. But I admit, it's laziness on the side of Microsoft that they report these.

Comment: Actually "." means "the current directory" and ".." means "the parent directory". It's totally useless that `FindFileNext` reports these and it's probably only done for compatibility reasons with antique Windows versions.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelWalz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
CStringArray GetAllFilesNames()
{
  WIN32_FIND_DATA fileData;
  memset(&fileData, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));
  HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile("d:\\test\\*", &fileData);
  CStringArray strArray;

  if (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    do
    {
      if (_tcscmp(fileData.cFileName, _T(".")) != 0 && // ignore "." and ".."
        _tcscmp(fileData.cFileName, _T("..")) != 0)
      {
        strArray.Add(fileData.cFileName);
      }
    } while (FindNextFile(handle, &fileData));

    FindClose(handle);
  }

  return strArray;
}
```

Disclaimer: this is untested and minimal error checking code just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Does `CStringArray` come with copy constructor?

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin good question, But the OP pretends that his code works.

Comment: Since the OP is asking for a "list of files" only, the loop should be ignoring entries that have the `FILE_FLAG_DIRECTORY` flag enabled in the `fileData.dwFileAttributes` field.

Answer (score 5):

Your code uses just Win32 API to traverse directory/folder. The MFC way of doing this is much simpler. The framework comes with `CFileFind` which is much easier to use. Also you can not return `CStringArray` as it does not have copy constructor. You should be using `CStringArray` reference as out param of your method

```
void CCL2ProjectDirectoryPage::GetAllFilesNames(CStringArray& files)
{
    CFileFind finder;
    // start working for files
    BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile(_T("d:\\test\\*"));
    while (bWorking)
    {
        bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();

        // skip . and .. files
        if (!finder.IsDots())
        {
            files.Add(finder.GetFileName());
        }
    }

}
```